# How do I disable app server embedded library(jar) for a particular WAR or EAR?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jboss, glassfish

Sometimes you may have a `third party libraries` in your project which can cause **conflicts** with you `server-embedded jars`. Removing embedded jars from your application server `lib folder` can break other deployed apps.

Is there a way to disable server-embedded jars for only one project in **TomEE**, JBoss, GlassFish?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JBoss, you can disable container managed libraries with a jboss-deployment-structure.xml descriptor in your WEB-INF directory.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding
      some dependencies -->
    <exclusions>
      <!-- This will cause the JBoss container to not provide your deployed 
         application's log4j dependencies. This way you can use an implementation 
         deployed with your artifact. -->
      <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

The documentation for class loading in JBoss AS 7 can be found [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7).

Comment: I added a link to the documentation for JBoss class loading.

Comment: In my case I included the module in mi jboss-deployment-structure and cleaned the libs in my app.  Everything was ok
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
 <dependencies>
         <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents" />
      </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>`