# How to solve conflict between Jboss libs and webapps libs

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, conflict, jboss5.x

I use JBoss 5.1 and I deploy an ear on it.

In my ear, few webapps are using some jars which are using by JBoss to.
For example, jboss use slf4j in version 1.5.6 and my webapps uses version 1.7.1
This two versions of slf4j are not compatible (see [Logging framework incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519978/logging-framework-incompatibility)).

Is there any way to say to JBoss to use his own lib but webapp have to use theirs ?

Edit : I don't want to change the version of JBoss I use.

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

Create jboss-deployment-structure.xml file in WEB-INF folder with deployment exclusions of jars which you want to attach. 
[How do I disable app server embedded library(jar) for a particular WAR or EAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002444/how-do-i-disable-app-server-embedded-libraryjar-for-a-particular-war-or-ear)

Comment: I'm also facing same problem with asm.jar. In jboss4.2.3 asm.jar is there, but our ear lib contains asm3.3.1. How can i exclude base version from jboss/lib and say take higher version from ear ??